# prestashop add extra tab to product management with some angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs, prestashop

I'm trying to add functionalities to prestashop product management system. With a simple module called *Advprod*.

Using *displayAdminProductsExtra* hook I was able to add section to product management in prestashop backoffice. In this new section I've to work with angular.

My actual tpl is correctly loaded by an ajax request (in the prestashop way) but it is never compiled by angular.

```
{literal}

<div id="lspc" class='panel'>
            <p>
                <input data-ng-model="prova" /> {{prova}}
            </p> 
</div>

{/literal}
```

As I understood prestashop build product management section loading all tabs initially empty, the content into the tabs is loaded after via ajax. Tab added by my module has id  "#product-tab-content-ModuleAdvprod" and it is present as the other tabs from the start and as the other tabs is empty.

When ajax response containing the tpl content arrives the tab is populated with an empty input text and *{{prova}}* (not compiled).

Google-ing a bit i found this article from angular documentation useful: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.injector

So I tried to do the same in prestashop:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function(){
    var idappel = "#product-tab-content-ModuleAdvprod"; //this element exists

    var app = angular.module("lspc", []);
    app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope){
      $scope.prova = "ci siamo";
    });

    /*
    from firebug I can clearly see that these attributes are correctly added
    */
    $(idappel).attr("data-ng-app", "lspc"); 
    $(idappel).attr("data-ng-controller", "MyCtrl");

    $(idappel).on("DOMSubtreeModified", function(){
        /*
        only when:
        - the content tab is changed
        - the tab contain the element with id lspc
        - element with id lspc is visible (user opened tab)
        - the content tab has not classes 'loading' and 'not-loaded'
        */ 
        if($("#lspc").size() 
            && $("#lspc").is(":visible")
            && !$(idappel).hasClass("loading") 
            && !$(idappel).hasClass("not-loaded")){


            $(idappel).unbind("DOMSubtreeModified");
            angular.element($(idappel)).injector().invoke(function($compile) {
                var scope = angular.element($(idappel)).scope();
                $compile($(idappel))(scope);
            });
        }   
    });
});
```

I always get the error angular.element($(idappel)).injector() is undefined.
But I'm sure that angular.element($(idappel)) is always a loaded html element.

Google-ing a little bit more I found someone that use setTimeout so I also tried to do:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    angular.element($(idappel)).injector().invoke(function($compile) {
        var scope = angular.element($(idappel)).scope();
        $compile($(idappel))(scope);
    });
}, 15000);
```

Also after 15 seconds angular.element($(idappel)).injector() results to be undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using angular.bootstrap.

Using hookBackOfficeHeader I've included a js file containing:

```
var app = angular.module("lspc", []);
app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope){
    $scope.prova = "ci siamo";
});
```

While in tpl I've:

```
{literal}
<script>
    angular.element(document).ready(function(){
        angular.bootstrap(angular.element($("#lspc")), ["lspc"]);
    });
</script>   
<div id="lspc" class='panel' data-ng-app='lspc' data-ng-controller='MyCtrl'>
    <p>
        <input data-ng-model="prova" /> {{prova}}
    </p> 
</div>

{/literal}
```